# how can i print value of input text type id in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<input type=text name=input id="in1" value=1 onclick=inputs()>
<input type=text name=input id="in2" value=2 onclick=inputs()>
<input type=text name=input id="in3" value=3 onclick=inputs()>
<input type=text name=input id="in4" value=4 onclick=inputs()>
<script type=text/javascript>
function inputs()
{
var val=document.getElementById();
document.write(val);
}
</script>
```

Actually, i want only onclick's input id in variable val. please help me.

Comment: Too many wrong answers to downvote...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe everyone else is reading a different question than I am but it seems like you want the value of the ID, not the value of the input.

```
<input type=text name=input id="in1" value=1 onclick=inputs(this.id)>
<input type=text name=input id="in2" value=2 onclick=inputs(this.id)>
<input type=text name=input id="in3" value=3 onclick=inputs(this.id)>
<input type=text name=input id="in4" value=4 onclick=inputs(this.id)>
<script type=text/javascript>
function inputs(val)
{
    document.write(val);
}
</script>
```

This will give you the ID of that element, not its value.  Which is what I hope I'm reading from this oddly worded question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type=text name=input id="in1" value=1 onclick=inputs(this.id)>
<input type=text name=input id="in2" value=2 onclick=inputs(this.id)>
<input type=text name=input id="in3" value=3 onclick=inputs(this.id)>
<input type=text name=input id="in4" value=4 onclick=inputs(this.id)>
<script type=text/javascript>
function inputs(id)
{
var val=id;
document.write(val);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="in1" value="1" onclick="inputs(this.id)">
<input type=text name=input id="in2" value=2 onclick="inputs(this.id)">
<input type=text name=input id="in3" value=3 onclick="inputs(this.id)">
<input type=text name=input id="in4" value=4 onclick="inputs(this.id)">
<script type=text/javascript>
function inputs(id)
{
var val=id
alert(val);
}
</script>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xA8kG/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type=text name=input id="in1" value=1 onclick=inputs(this)>
<input type=text name=input id="in2" value=2 onclick=inputs(this)>
<input type=text name=input id="in3" value=3 onclick=inputs(this)>
<input type=text name=input id="in4" value=4 onclick=inputs(this)>
<script type=text/javascript>
function inputs(dis)
{
var val=dis.value;
document.write(val);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this, Added `this` in `inputs(this)`

HTML:

```
<input type=text name=input id="in1" value=1 onclick=inputs(this)>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type=text/javascript>
function inputs(d)
{   
   document.write(d.value);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<input type=text name=input id="in1" value=1 onclick=inputs(this)>
<input type=text name=input id="in2" value=2 onclick=inputs(this)>
<input type=text name=input id="in3" value=3 onclick=inputs(this)>
<input type=text name=input id="in4" value=4 onclick=inputs(this)>
<script type=text/javascript>
function inputs(el)
{
 var val=el.getAttribute('id');
 document.write(val);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do you want the id of input element which is clicked?

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="in1" value="1" onclick="inputs(this)">
<input type="text" name="input" id="in2" value="2" onclick="inputs(this)">
<input type="text" name="input" id="in3" value="3" onclick="inputs(this)">
<input type="text" name="input" id="in4" value="4" onclick="inputs(this)">
<script type=text/javascript>
function inputs(elem)
{
var val=elem.id;
console.log(val);
}
</script>
```

Check value in console

Comment: try now u ll get ids of input

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
onclick=inputs(this)
```

And

```
function inputs(element)
{
   var val = element.id;
   // rest of the code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**It will get id of clicked input field.Try this:**
**DEMO :** http://jsfiddle.net/6Z2fR/

```
<input type=text name=input id="in1" value=1 onclick=inputs(this)>
<input type=text name=input id="in2" value=2 onclick=inputs(this)>
<input type=text name=input id="in3" value=3 onclick=inputs(this)>
<input type=text name=input id="in4" value=4 onclick=inputs(this)>

  <script type=text/javascript>
        function inputs(e)
        {
            var val=e.id;
            console.log(val);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: @user3133809 :Just change scrip position. Updated link:  http://jsfiddle.net/6Z2fR/2/   Did you take a look at this link?

Answer (score 0):

Most easiest way

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="in1" value="1" onfocus="inputs(this.value)">
<script type=text/javascript>
function inputs(x)
{
document.write(x);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is better to use jQuery, you can change event like mouseover/keydown/hover and make code not too mess :P

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="in1">
<input type="text" name="input" id="in2">
<input type="text" name="input" id="in3">
<input type="text" name="input" id="in4">

<script type="text/javascript">
(function ($) {
    $('input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        $(this).click(function () {
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Or just see the demo in JSFiddle, [click me!](http://jsfiddle.net/s3YdW/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
<input type="text" name="input" id="in1" value="1" onclick="inputs(this)">
<input type="text" name="input" id="in2" value="2" onclick="inputs(this)">
<input type="text" name="input" id="in3" value="3" onclick="inputs(this)">
<input type="text" name="input" id="in4" value="4" onclick="inputs(this)">

function inputs(element) {
    var id = element.id;
    var val = element.name;
    alert(val ,id);
}
```

[fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xA8kG/2/)